# What is derivation method of laplacian for spherical coordinate?

Tags: calculus

I know what laplacian of spherical coordinate is, but i what to know method of derivation laplacian for spherical coordinate:
$$dl^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2$$

---

i know it is not laplacian but it is also base of spherical coordinate.
i want to know how to use this to derivate laplacian?

Comment: The expression you presented isn't laplacian, so what are you searching for - infinitesimal length or laplacian?

Answer (score 2):

My favourite method is based on the idea that integration is easier than changing variables in higher partial derivatives in multi-d.

Start with Gauss's theorem: $$\int_V\Delta u\,dV=\int_{\partial V}n\cdot\nabla u\,dS$$
where $n$ is the outward unit normal. Now let $V$ be a spherical “box” $r_1<r<r_2$, $\phi_1<\phi<\phi_2$, $\theta_1<\theta<\theta_2$ and evaluate the surface integral.

Two of the contributions will be $$\begin{multline*}\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\int_{\phi_1}^{\phi_2} \bigl(r_2^2u_r(r_2,\phi,\theta)-r_1^2u_r(r_1,\phi,\theta)\bigr)\sin\theta\,d\phi\,d\theta \\=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\int_{\phi_1}^{\phi_2}\int_{r_1}^{r_2}\frac{(r^2u_r)_r}{r^2}\cdot r^2\sin\theta\,dr\,d\phi\,d\theta,\end{multline*}$$
where you recognize the volume form in spherical coordinates at the end (that is why I divided and multiplied by $r^2$).

If $u$ is radially symmetric, now you're done, as the other contributions must vanish: You must have $$\Delta u=\frac{(r^2u_r)_r}{r^2}.$$

In the general case, you must also handle the other four contributions to the surface integral in a similar fashion.

In summary, the idea is that if $w$ has the same integral over any spherical box as $\Delta u$ has, then $\Delta u=w$.

Comment: very cool method